# Передача media-правила через iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, media-queries

#### Описание

Есть у меня 2 страницы. Так как один из них должен стоять в другом через iframe, обозначим её как дочерний, а другой — родительский. Обеим страницам подключен один и тот же css документ, в котором есть media-правило для размера экрана:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Когда размеры меняются, срабатывает media-правило для родительской страницы, но никак не реагирует дочерняя страница через iframe.

#### Дополнительно

Через час беседы с GPT решили поставить обработчик:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
    const width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    for (const iframe of document.querySelectorAll(`iframe`)) {
        iframe.contentWindow.resizeTo(width, height);
    }
});
```

Но тут блокирует CORS со словами:

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Хотя обе страницы на одном домене.

#### Вопрос

Что вообще можно делать в таком ситуации? Как мне передать отклики media-правил через iframe?

Comment: С `iframe` есть особенность, возможно ты на нее и попал... https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-communication#ifreym-podozhdite-dokument

Comment: Так же можно использовать "общение между окнами" (обход CORS) - https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-communication#obmen-soobscheniyami-mezhdu-oknami

Comment: @ksa если про блокировку CORS, то это не совсем. Размеры экрана меняю когда iframe уже загружен и все равно блокирует.

Comment: Тогда переходи на `postMessage`...

Comment: @ksa вариант с `postMessage` на самом деле смотрел. Отказался от него, потому что надо будет изменить код сайта который в iframe. Это создает проблемы тем, что на странице может быть много таких iframe-ов и я не смогу для каждого изменить код внутреннего сайта.